# How do I use multiple functions in one JS file

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

Sometime ago a Web designer showed me how to organise my functions on one JS file. However, I am having trouble getting it to work. There are no errors on the page but the functions don't seem to run?

The idea is, if the item (Class) is in the HTML I run the JQuery function which is in my functions.js, if not, no need to do anything. I have created a CodePen so people can take a look.

Any help welcome :)

```js
(function($) {
  var siteScripts = {
    /*
     * function onReady
     */
    onReady: function() {
      this.boxOne();
      this.boxTwo();
    },
    
    boxOne: function() {
      if ($('.box-one').length) {
        $('.box-one p').html('Canary One');
      }
    },

    boxTwo: function() {
      if ($('.box-two').length) {
        $('.box-two p').html('Canary Two');
      }
    }
  };

  $().ready(function() {
    //jQuery.noConflict();
    siteScripts.onReady();
  });

  function makeShort() {

  }
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<h1>Hello World</h1>

<div class="box-one">
    <p>I love my canary</p>
</div>

<div class="box-two">
    <p>I love my canary</p>
</div>

<input type="button" id="test" value="Submit">

<!-- jQuery  -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: No sure what why my functions won't run?

Comment: There is a reason why you get the message `Links to codepen.io must be accompanied by code.`. Questions you ask on SO should always be self-contained. A complete working example  e.g. in  `codepen.io` is always helpful but it should not replace the code in your question.

Comment: It doesn't matter where you put the functions, so long as the code is valid and loads dependencies (like libraries or plugins) first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just pass the jQuery object to the function:

```
(function ($) {
    ...
})($);
```

This will solve your original problem.

Also, your selectors in the `boxOne` and `boxTwo` functions seems to be wrong, as they select all paragraphs, not just the ones in the corresponding boxes.

The selector in `boxOne` should be:

```
$('.box-one p')
```

and in `boxTwo` it should be:

```
$('.box-two p')
```

Comment: Thanks for that, but this isn't what I am trying to solve. The Codepen fiddle shows what should happen. :)

Comment: Then what is you problem? It does not run as is at all.

Comment: @user1432315 You wrote "the functions don't seem to run", and that's what meskobalazs solved. If there's something else that's wrong, you need to describe it exactly.

Comment: You're wondering why you're function won't run, and @meskobalazs's answer actually makes it work. Either pass $ or jQuery.

Comment: I'm also confused by the downvotes on this. It answers the question and goes a step further by addressing why the selectors are behaving as (we think) they should.

Comment: I agree with everyone. I also created a fiddle the shows that it works. http://jsfiddle.net/m0nk3y/47gfzucv/

Comment: Thank you meskobalazs I did wonder about the if I neded to specify the class then the p as well in the JQuery. However, the text still doesn't change in the p tags so I take this as the function isnt running?

Comment: Technically, you don't need the `if` statement there; if you do `$('.box-two p').html("Canary Two")`, and `".box-two"` or `".box-two p"` are empty, simply nothing will happen.

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle. I see now. I took the last line off my script (where it says JQuery) before I started as it seemed to throw up a JQuery error in my console. Then I had a go at creating my functions. However, it seems I needed si I have put this last line back in, as in the Fiddles. This makes the functions run and doesn't error any more :)

Comment: @user1432315 Don't forgot to accept an answer if it helped you (green checkmark to the left of the answer). Might want to do that in some other questions too.